# API calls in componentDidUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am making API calls in the `componentDidMount()` method as recommended by React.
Inside the component I have a `<Link>` which points to the same component with different URL params.

However when I click on the `<Link>` the `componentDidMount()` is not called and I can't make API calls with updated URL params.

So I tried putting the API calls inside `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`

This results in stack overflow as the API calls set state triggering `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` which again make the API calls leading to infinite loop.

How do I overcome this?

What is the recommended solution which fits into React philosophy?

Comment: Please post code snippets of relevant components in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Inside the component I have a  which points to the same component with different URL params

This means the component is not unmounted/remounted as it's the same component, so `componentDidMount` will not be called.

> API calls set state triggering componentDidUpdate() and componentWillReceiveProps() which again make the API calls leading to infinite loop

You should make the API call in `componentDidUpdate` (`componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated and async calls should not be executed here anyway), but check if it's already been executed by checking if the data returned by the API call is there or changed, to avoid infinite re-rendering:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.data.length === 0) { // or compare with `prevState`
    // make the api call
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `componentDidUpdate()` receives previous props by using it you can if the props are updated or not... if updated then call API. In my project I am doing it as follows:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.category !== this.props.match.params.category) {
        this.getBlogList(this.props.match.params.category);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -4):

remove componentDidUpdate and use only componentWillReceiveProps(){ <--- and call api here}

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is deprecated. However it's not a good practice to use it for asynchronous tasks